# Urban Airship push report with deeplink information

Tags: urbanairship.com

http://docs.urbanairship.com/api/ua.html#push-report

Browsing over the above site, there's several ways of getting push reports. However I want to get a list of send push messages, including the deeplink that was associated with it.

Like http://docs.urbanairship.com/api/ua.html#response-listing, but with its payload (push text, deeplinks etc.).

I know this is possible though the urban airship admin-interface (push log), however is it possible through the API?

Any experience or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The full push payload is available via the [Push Body Event](http://docs.urbanairship.com/api/connect.html#push-body-event). These events are accessible via the [Connect](http://docs.urbanairship.com/api/connect.html#) product.

Retaining long-lived API-accessible push payloads is much more resource intensive than retaining short-lived admin-accessible push payloads. This is a likely reason for including Push Body Events in the Connect product instead of including them in the free plan.